# How to iterate defaultdict(list) and make a json output in python?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

How to iterate `defaultdict(list)` in python in such a way so that I can get counts of each strings sorted by highest number. In my below code, I am reading csv file to

So I read about it and found I can use `collections.Counter` here but my `poc` column also has lot of `empty/null` strings and it is also counting those as well. Is there any way to avoid that? Also can we generate a json with that result if there is any way?

```
import sys
import csv
import collections
from collections import defaultdict

filename = sys.argv[1]
columns = defaultdict(list)

with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for (k,v) in row.items():
            columns[k].append(v)

print(collections.Counter(columns['poc']))
```

This is the output I get as of now:

```
Counter({'': 100,'\health':2,'Checking records':2,...})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) builtin function to remove empty strings or other "false-y" values such as `None`, `0` or `False`.

```
collections.Counter(filter(None, columns['poc']))
```

If you want to exclude empty strings but keep other false-y values, use a lambda to define the filtering criteria.

```
collections.Counter(filter(lambda x: x != '', columns['poc']))
```

`Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so an instance can be serialised to JSON like any dictionary:  `json.dumps(counter)`

Comment: if I do that then output is not in the sorted order somehow. any idea why?

Comment: You can sort the json by its keys like this: `json.dumps(my_counter, sort_keys=True)`.  You can't sort by values.

Comment: yeah got it but in my case I wanted highest value key to be at the top I guess.

Comment: You could dump `sorted(my_counter.most_common(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`, but that will give you an array of arrays rather than an object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can do done simply using dictionary.

```
key  = dict(collections.Counter(columns['poc']))
#removes the empty element
key.pop('')
print(key)
```

Comment: use key.pop('')

Comment: It's not counting correctly with this solution. Count is off.

Comment: sorry it is counting correct but it's not sorted by highest count number. Is there any way to achieve that as well?